# How do you cite a scholar as in agreement with an argument?

Tags: latin

I've noted your conversation regarding the Latin *pace*, meaning "not in agreement with." Doesn't *cf* mean the same thing? What terms is appropriate when citing a scholar who is, in fact, in agreement with the stated argument?

Comment: As far as I know, **cf** stands for *compare*.

Comment: In textual criticism it's N *prob.* (for L *probante*) or N *approb.* (for L *approbante*), where N is the name or symbol for the authority agreeing.

Comment: @StoneyB Please do not post answers in the comment field.

Comment: @RyanJensen It's not an answer, merely a suggestion for further investigation; I've never seen this outside of very old-fashioned textual criticism.

Comment: Latin *pace* means "with respect" (lit. 'peace').  It doesn't by itself indicate whether you agree or disagree with the respected authority.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a site for learners of the **English** language, might it not be a good idea to use English words rather than abbreviations of Latin words, especially when, *pace* @aml, those Latin words are not always used in ways that are strictly correct in Latin? (It occurs to me that the colloquial modern English translation of 'pace' in this context is 'no offence [meant]', but I would not recommend using those words in a formal context.)

So, nobody will misunderstand if you quote something and then comment "with which [Name] agrees [insert reference]". As @StoneyB, notes the Latin version is now very old-fashioned. I would say that it has reached the point of being pretentious to use these Latin abbreviations.

Comment: "concurs" might also be a good word to use.

Comment: @rjpond You are right